# How can I open a folder in Windows Explorer?

Tags: c#, explorer

I don't need any kind of interface. I just need the program to be an `.exe` file that opens a directory (eg. F:).

What kind of template would I use in C#? Would something other than Visual Studio work better? Would a different process entirely work better?

Comment: You would probably used `Windows Form Application` _C#_ template in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 26):

In `C#` you can do just that:

```
Process.Start(@"c:\users\");
```

This line will throw `Win32Exception` when folder doesn't exists. If you'll use `Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\folder\");` it will just opened another folder (if the one you specified doesn't exists).

So if you want to open the folder **ONLY** when it exists, you should do:

```
try
{
    Process.Start(@"c:\users22222\");
}
catch (Win32Exception win32Exception)
{
    //The system cannot find the file specified...
    Console.WriteLine(win32Exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: Note that if you use this answer, the suffixed `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` is critical. Otherwise, if there is another folder in the same directory with an extension such as `.exe` or `.cmd`, explorer will launch to that other folder instead of the one you intended to open. See [how VS fails at this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/104305/.html).

Comment: For .NET Core 3.0+ this will throw an exception, because UseShellExecute property is false by default. Use solution as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846709/process-start-in-core-3-0-does-not-open-a-folder-just-by-its-name)

Comment: Don't forget to call dispose on the Process 
```using(Process.Start(@"c:\users22222\")) { }```

Answer (score 9):

Create a batch file , for example open.bat

And write this line

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "folder path"
```

If you really want to do it in C#

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\...");
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can remove all the superfluous information about the batch file, as clearly the OP wants to open it using C#.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) API with the `explore` verb as documented in [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct SHELLEXECUTEINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpVerb;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpParameters;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpDirectory;
    public int nShow;
    public IntPtr hInstApp;
    public IntPtr lpIDList;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpClass;
    public IntPtr hkeyClass;
    public uint dwHotKey;
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public IntPtr hProcess;
}

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ShellExecuteEx(ref SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpExecInfo);

private const int SW_SHOW = 5;

public static bool OpenFolderInExplorer(string folder)
{
    var info = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
    info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<SHELLEXECUTEINFO>();
    info.lpVerb = "explore";
    info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    info.lpFile = folder;
    return ShellExecuteEx(ref info);
}
```

---

Code like `Process.Start("explorer.exe", folder);` is actually saying "throw the command string *explorer.exe [folder]* at the shell's command interpreter, and hope for the best". This might open an explorer window at the specified folder, if the shell decides that Microsoft's *Windows Explorer* is the program that should be run, and that it parses the (possibly unescaped) folder argument how you think it would.

In short, `ShellExecuteEx` with the `explore` verb is documented to do exactly what you want, while starting `explorer.exe` with an argument just happens to have the same outcome, under the condition that a bunch of assumptions are true on the end-users system.

Comment: Very precise answer. Little note: needs to include `System.Runtime.InteropServices`

Comment: use `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO))` when targeting .NET Framework earlier than ~4.5

Answer (score 2):

Hope that you are looking for [`FolderBrowserDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383879%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) if so, following code will help you:

```
string folderPath = "";
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    folderPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath ;
}
```

Or else if you want to open Mycomputer through code, then following option will help you:

```
string myComputerPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer", myComputerPath);
```