# Process.Start in Core 3.0 does not open a folder just by its name

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

I have just migrated a desktop app from Framework to Core 3.0.

`Process.Start(path_to_folder);` workes fine in Framework but throws `Win32Exception: Access denied` in the Core. `Process.Start("explorer.exe", path_to_folder);` works fine on both.

Is this a bug or limitation in the Core?

Comment: Sounds more like the old behavior is an unintended side-effect of how things were done in .NET Framework, as `Process.Start(string)` was always meant to take a *file name*, not a folder path.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suspect the [`ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) is what would allow this to work on .NET Framework.  From the documentation...

> The default is `true` on .NET Framework apps and `false` on .NET Core apps.

...and the `Process.Start()` overloads that just take `string` parameters will likely just leave that property at the default.  To work around this, create your own `ProcessStartInfo` with the `UseShellExecute` property set to `true` and pass that to an overload of `Process.Start()` instead...

```cs
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path_to_folder) {
    UseShellExecute = true
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

---

For completeness, when I try running this...

```cs
Process.Start(Environment.SystemDirectory);
```

...in .NET Core 3.0 I get this exception...

> Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
>
> > - at [System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61a6264018989e06d314b68d57bd91b4b72e4360/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Windows.cs#L454)
> > - at [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61a6264018989e06d314b68d57bd91b4b72e4360/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.cs#L1186)
> > - at [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61a6264018989e06d314b68d57bd91b4b72e4360/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.cs#L1256)
> > - at [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61a6264018989e06d314b68d57bd91b4b72e4360/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.cs#L1230)

The missing link between `Process.Start()` and `Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)` is [`Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61a6264018989e06d314b68d57bd91b4b72e4360/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Win32.cs#L24), which branches based on the value of `UseShellExecute` and I imagine gets inlined.  The exception appears to be [thrown](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61a6264018989e06d314b68d57bd91b4b72e4360/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Windows.cs#L616) after a call to 
[`CreateProcess()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/88f40addc220c73794f962f10d288c20c416ede1/src/Common/src/Interop/Windows/Kernel32/Interop.CreateProcess.cs#L15), presumably because a directory path is specified as the file to executable.

Note that if you pass a path to a non-executable file to that same `Process.Start(String fileName)` overload the exception message becomes "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

The reason why calling [`Process.Start(String fileName, String arguments)`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/61a6264018989e06d314b68d57bd91b4b72e4360/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.cs#L1243) works despite following largely the same code path is because the [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) instance it creates under the covers has a [`FileName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename) that *does* refer to a file (`explorer.exe`) that can be directly executed even if `UseShellExecute` is `false`.

Comment: Yes, it works with the property defined. It's worth mentioning that the path should be defined in the FileName property in this case.