# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Exception thrown in Net 5.0 project but not in .Net Framework 4.7.1

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-5

```
Process.Start(sourceFile);
```

That's it. That's the code. I am currently re-writing some software targeting .NET 5.0 from a project written in C# targeting .NET Framework.

When the button is pressed, it is supposed to open a file. In the .NET Framework 4.7.1 it opens the file, even if someone already has it open. The process being started, AutoCAD in this case, handles the read-only aspect of the file as it normally would.

When I use the same exact code on the same exact file in .NET 5.0, it throws a System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (32): *The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.* exception.

I know what the exception means, I just don't know why it's being thrown when there is no issue opening the file in the original project.

Has .NET 5.0 changed how this works? I'm at a loss as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846709/process-start-in-core-3-0-does-not-open-a-folder-just-by-its-name (see first answer)

Comment: I can confirm that I also get an access denied error in .NET 5.0 when I try to open a directory using Process.Start(). You're right, they might be related.

Answer (score 0):

@klaus-gütter posted a link that did contain the answer, though it seems a bit inconvenient.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path_to_folder) {
UseShellExecute = true
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

is the way to make this work.